# Search in Chrome is occasionally being hijacked by a rogue extension. Short of testing each one, how can I figure out which one it is?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, spyware, adware

Every few searches I do from the omnibar, the Google search results will appear, then the page flashes, reloads, and shows search results in Bing instead. I'm on a relatively clean macOS install, so it's obvious that one of my Chrome extensions has gone rogue. But I have a lot of extensions, and the issue does not manifest every time I search, so is there another way I can figure out which extension is responsible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it may not be possible. With some careful looking in the debugger console (F12) you could probably determine which extension is triggering it if you had the console open when the bad search was triggered, however, it would also be reported as `chrome-extension://[hash id]` rather than the extension name.

Ultimately it is probably less time to disable them all and turn them back on one at a time until the behavior is replicated.

Comment: Or divide and conquer, which may be faster. Disable 1/2 and see which 1/2 it is in. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Right now, I have a rogue extension that hijacks my Chrome when visiting certain domains, but stops when the DevTools is open. As a javascript developer, I'm aware that certain techniques can be used to detect if DevTools is open or not. So yes, maybe divide and conquer is the better approach.